# What are the FragColor index and FragColor number?

Tags: opengl

I have been read http://docs.gl/gl4/glGetFragDataIndex and http://docs.gl/gl4/glGetFragDataLocation, I want to know what are those feature and what are difference between them. The document said they separately indicate the number of FragColor bound to and the index, could anyone tell me what are index and number of FragColor?